# Difference between scp and sftp within curl

Tags: sftp, scp, curl

I have encountered a serious problem with curl.
I want to copy a file from a raspberry on a remote server working under Windows 10. RSA key is installed on the server, everything is working passwordless with ssh.

If I run the following command:

```
curl -k -v -u user.me: --pubkey .ssh/id_rsa.pub -T ./image1.jpg sftp://user.me@xx.xx.xx.xx/c:/Users/user.me/Documents/image1.jpg
```

the file is successfully uploaded.

If I run the same command, changing the protocol to scp:
curl -k -v -u user.me: --pubkey .ssh/id_rsa.pub -T ./image1.jpg scp://user.me@xx.xx.xx.xx/c:/Users/user.me/Documents/image1.jpg

I got an error:

> curl: (67) Authentication failure

If I try to use scp directly, it works fine:
scp ./image1.jpg user.me@xx.xx.xx.xx:c:/Users/user.me/Documents/image1.jpg

Could you please explain to me why I get a different behaviour with scp and sftp when I am using curl? Is there anything to be done to make curl uploading successfully with protocol scp?

Comment: "--pubkey .ssh/id_rsa.pub" I know you said the sftp case works, but you wouldn't normally use the .pub file here. Try using the id_rsa file (no extension).

Comment: Why do you want to use SCP? SCP has been largely replaced by SFTP, which is a superset containing SCP's features plus a bunch of other capabilities. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol#Capabilities

Comment: @FrankThomas I must not use other capabilities such as remote folder creation, it must be forbidden.

Comment: @Kenster I am using the public key because I get an error if I use the private key: `SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to extract public key from private key file: Method unimplemented in libgcrypt backend` (for info, libgcrypt is version 20.2.8). I don't understand why. If I use the same key with scp or ssh, it does not complain.

Comment: @Kenster Sorry, libgcrypt is version 1.9.4-5, debian os.

Comment: It looks like you should pass both the private and public key files to curl: "... --key .ssh/id_rsa --pubkey .ssh/id_rsa.pub ..."

Comment: @Kenster Then I get a different error, curl (25), failed to send file. File is existing, no problem with that.

Comment: I think I should stick with sftp and put some restriction server-side to secure the access. I dont' understand what is going on, but for sure sftp is working well.